# Maven site:deploy target Overwrite

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I'm using the site distribution feature of maven (version 3.0.3) to upload generated content for our projects.  It's configured in our pom.xml as such:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>OUR_ID_HERE</id>
        <name>PROJECT_NAME</name>
        <url>scp://<host>/<parent folder>/${project.artifactId}</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

It works fine, however I'm noticing that the **"Last Published: "** portion of the pages is only updated when I physically remove the contents of the target folder.  I'm wondering if this is a bug, and if so, would it be possible to configure the maven-site-plugin (version 3.0-beta-3) to clean out the target folder prior to unzipping the uploaded files to work around it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you done a mvn clean site site:deploy?

Comment: Karl-Heinz, this won't help. Files aren't overwritten in the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has already been reported: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE-250

Comment: Thanks, this really explains what I'm experiencing.  Man, I wish that feature is added because it would be very useful.